# Getting value from jquery datetimepicker in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Im playing around with a booking-system in MVC.
I have a view where you select 3 diffrent values (treatment, hairdresser and date).

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("testing", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) { 
<p id="frisor"> Frisör: @Html.DropDownList("Fris", "All")<a class="butt" onclick="showdiv()">Nästa steg</a></p>
<p id="behandling">Behandling: @Html.DropDownList("Cat", "All")<a class="butt" onclick="showdiv2()">Nästa steg</a></p>

<p>
    Datum:
    <input type="text" id="MyDate" />    <-------This is a jquery datetimepicker
</p
```

I would like to save the customers three choices in three properties i have created.
 My post method looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Testing(string Fris, string Cat, DateTime MyDate)
        {
            kv.treatment = Cat
            kv.Hairdresser = Fris;
            kv.Datum = MyDate;
            return View();
        }
```

I get the two first (hairdresser,treatment) fine,
 the problem is that i dont know how to get the value from the jquery datetimpicker.
 Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input` needs a `name` in order to be included in the form post:

```
<input type="text" id="MyDate" name="MyDate" />
```

Otherwise the browser won't include it in the posted data, so it will never reach the server for model binding.  (And, of course, the `name` has to match the method argument name for the model binder to match them.)